# disable submit button according to validation of multiple inputs

Tags: jquery, submit, attr

I've checked every input with keyup or change events with different js files. So user can see his/her mistake by the time it is made. Now i want to collect all validation info of inputs and make click event to submit button to enable or disable the submit.

I've tried to create a custom attribute named "isvalid" for all inputs and according to validation result set "isvalid" as "true" or "false". My plan was to check all isvalid values and make disable or enable submit button. But i can only get changed attribute value in same event, but not in different js files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give each input a specific classname to indicate it requires validation, and loop through them when you submit your form:

```
$('.submit_button').click(function(event) {
   $('.required').each(function() {
      if (!this.value) {
         event.preventDefault();
         alert('Please fill in all required fields');
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, so i need to check all inputs again by the click event, right?

Comment: Yes. You can specify particular classnames for particular data types you're expecting (telephone numbers, e-mail addresses, etc.) You shouldn't rely on client-side validation, so make sure your server-side script is also validating.